# Order posts using a custom array

Tags: query-posts, wp-query, sort

I have an array of post ids which I'm passing to query_posts using 'post__in'.

My question is how can I use the order from my array rather than ordering by 'date' etc?

Comment: order by what??

Comment: do the answers to this question help? [http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/27832/wp-query-orderby-none-problem]

Answer (score 3):

You would need to build your own query and pass it to query_posts i.e.

if your array of post ids is:

```
array (10,21,1)   // corresponding to post ids.
```

then you can query this way:

```
select * from wp_posts where `ID` in (10, 21, 2)
order by field(ID,10,21,2)
```

This will give you a result set in the order of your post ids array.

HTH

Comment: This is a great way to accomplish this. If you don't want to sacrifice the benefits of using query_posts, you can also chain into the `posts_orderby` filter to alter the orderby and use FIELD(ID, ...). Furthermore, to keep it dynamic, you can use, for a given array $arr, `'FIELD(ID, '.implode(',',$arr).')'`. [See the Codex for a good writeup of the posts_orderby filter](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/posts_orderby)