# Wp-query Order By problem

Tags: functions, wp-query, customization, shortcode

I'm trying to sort a query according to the order they write it in but it takes an order by ID.

The variable $idpaginas prints: 20659,20626,20585,20616,18464,19748,19991,18520,20588,21268,18753,20556,21277,18829,18551,21132

But after the query, it prints: 18520,18520,18551,18753,18829.....

```
function LoopMode($atts, $output = null, $my_query = null, $query_args = null) {
    // Params extraction
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        'idpaginas'   => '',
        'style'       => '',
    ), $atts));

    $query_args = array(
        'post_status'    => 'publish',
        'post__in'       => explode( ",", $idpaginas ),
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_type'      => 'page',
        'order_by'       => 'post__in',
        'order'          => 'ASC',
    );
    if(empty($style)){ $style = '2'; }
    // Run query
    $my_query = new WP_Query( $query_args );
    //$output = '';
    while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
        <div class="cluster-box col-<?php echo $style; ?>">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" class="cluster-mcl-link">
                <div class="mcl-cluster">
                    <div class="mcl-cluster-img" style="background-image:url(<?php the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>);">
                        <div class="mcl-cluster-title"><h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
    <?php endwhile;
    $my_query = null; $my_query = $temp;
    $output = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    wp_reset_postdata();
    return $output;
}
add_shortcode('cluster', 'LoopMode');
```

I have tried to remove args "order_by" and "order" values but it still continues to order it as he wants.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to wpse! have you tried with `'order_by' => 'post__in'` and without `'order' => 'ASC'`? Your code seems fine apart from that.

Comment: Hi! thanks!. Yes, I've tried it but it doesn't work. I do not know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Could you include a `print_r` or `var_dump` of the `$query_args` variable, maybe something in it is incorrect.

Comment: Sure!:

`array(5) { ["post_status"]=> string(7) "publish" ["post__in"]=> array(16) { [0]=> string(5) "20659" [1]=> string(5) "20626" [2]=> string(5) "20585" [3]=> string(5) "20616" [4]=> string(5) "18464" [5]=> string(5) "19748" [6]=> string(5) "19991" [7]=> string(5) "18520" [8]=> string(5) "20588" [9]=> string(5) "21268" [10]=> string(5) "18753" [11]=> string(5) "20556" [12]=> string(5) "21277" [13]=> string(5) "18829" [14]=> string(5) "18551" [15]=> string(5) "21132" } ["posts_per_page"]=> int(-1) ["post_type"]=> string(4) "page" ["order_by"]=> string(8) "post__in" }`

Comment: its hard to understand it if you paste it in the comment, please edit your question to include this dump, and if you can, format it. You can wrap the dump in `<pre>` tags, it will output a formated result

Comment: `$my_query = $temp;` doesn't make sense it should go, and the `extract` call is dangerous, you should pull your shortcode attributes from the attributes parameter instead of using `extract`

Comment: Thanks for your input Tom, I have removed it.

Answer (score 1):

The "problem" seems to be the default value that order receives, its always DESC unless told otherwise.

You will need to create your own order after getting the posts, so something like this.

```php
$my_query = new WP_Query($query_args);

$ordered_posts = [];

foreach(explode(',', $idpaginas) as $rpid) {
    foreach($my_query->posts as $index => $fpid) {
        if($fpid->ID == $rpid) $ordered_posts[] = $my_query->posts[$index];
    }
}

$my_query->posts = $ordered_posts;

while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();
```

This code was based on [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/27832/wp-query-orderby-none-problem) question, edited it a bit to fit your needs.

Comment: Thank you !!! I promise you that I have looked everywhere but I have not seen that post. Solved as you have commented. Thanks, again.